# Memory usage by DEFLATE algorithm

Tags: algorithm, zip, compression, huffman-code, deflate

Many implementations of the DEFLATE algorithm allow for stream-based inputs. An example is Java's `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream`. As far as I'm aware, DEFLATE builds a Huffman tree prior to compression and writes this tree at the BEGINNING of a .zip file.

However, in order to build a Huffman tree, the program needs counts of the most frequently occurring characters, which it has only after reading the file. If the stream is so large that it cannot fit in memory at once, how is the Huffman tree built?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEFLATE compresses data in blocks.  Each block includes its own tree/counts, and is usually about 16KB uncompressed.

The format is specified in the [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951)

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to check existence / size of those blocks? Because when I do `unzip -l file.zip`, I only see the one file that I zipped. Also is it theoretically possible to decode/inflate these blocks independently?

Comment: The normal tools you use on zip files will not expose the block structure.  I added a link the RFC that defines it.  Theoretically, it is possible to decode a block independently IF you can figure out where it starts.  There are no markers that identify the block ends that could not also appear within blocks, so identifying them would require some cleverness and would not be 100% reliable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! One more question though: are LZSS back-references allowed between blocks? Or are they truly independent?

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, ZIP-formatted files are supposed to be at most 2^32 bytes ~ 4Gb in size. However, `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream` method can output archives larger than 5Gb (just checked it myself). Do you happen to know the reason for that?

Comment: Back-references can point into preceding blocks, but the max distance is 32KB.   I don't know why .zip would be limited to 4GB -- probably due to 4 byte entries in the header, of course -- but the deflate format itself has no such limit.

Comment: The original zip specification set the 4Gb size. If the zip file uses the Zip64 extension that limit becomes 2^64 bytes --   see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)#ZIP64

Comment: [infgen](https://github.com/madler/infgen) will disassemble a deflate stream and expose the block structure. Yes, blocks can refer to strings in previous blocks and that cross block boundaries. The .zip format does allow for larger than 4GB zip files and zip file contents.